# IntelliJ IDEA 15 issues with CSS Class AutoComplete

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea, autocomplete

I've just downloaded IntelliJ IDEA 15 and am having issues with CSS class autocomplete from linked stylesheets.  An example is when I link Bootstrap's stylesheet in the header as shown below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The CSS classes don't autocomplete.  The only way I've been able to achieve this is by actually attaching the stylesheet within my project.  On the contrary, my JavaScript linked assets show correctly and can also be referenced within the project.  I have downloaded most all of the necessary plugins including LiveEdit, Emmet, CSS-x-fire, and all other necessary tools.

If anyone can help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.  This software seems to be very robust and I'd like to continue using the IntelliJ product suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to remove `Web facet` from your project module. (Open the project structure dialog) It helped me in similar situation.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I removed Web facet from my project module and it's working correctly now.